# Making counter using closure and self-invoking function

Tags: javascript, closures, self-invoking-function

I'm wondering why this code doesn't work,

```
var uniqueInteger = function() {
    var counter = 0;
    return function() { return counter++; }
};

console.log(uniqueInteger()());  // 0
console.log(uniqueInteger()());  // 0
console.log(uniqueInteger()());  // 0 
console.log(uniqueInteger()());  // 0
```

and this code does. The only difference is making the function self invoked instead of invoking it in console.log()

```
var uniqueInteger = (function() {
    var counter = 0;
    return function() { return counter++; }
}());

console.log(uniqueInteger());  // 0
console.log(uniqueInteger());  // 1
console.log(uniqueInteger());  // 2 
console.log(uniqueInteger());  // 3
```

I'm very new to JS so please excuse my noobness. Thanks!

Comment: the difference is that in your first example, you always call `uniqueInteger` and thus always redefining the variable `counter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second code created a closure with `var counter = 0` only once since when defining uniqueInteger, it called a function that returned a function where initialization is done. The first code creates `var counter = 0` every time you call it.

Note that with the first code you can do:

```
ui = uniqueInteger();
console.log(ui()); // 0
console.log(ui()); // 1
ui2 = uniqueInteger();
console.log(ui()); // 2
console.log(ui2()); // 0
console.log(ui()); // 3
console.log(ui2()); // 1
```